# git-like history derived database

Tags: git, security, rdbms, integrity

I am designing a highly sensitive software based on RDBMS one thing that bothers me is data being compromised through unintentional/malicious acts. Hence I would like to traceback changes to identify origin of changes to pin-point such activity. I believe it would be useful to maintain transaction history in such a way that such activities can be discovered, and also to restore database to the last uncompromised state, and still having list of later transactions that can be committed selectively. And having a git-like feature to immediately identifying any tampering would be useful.

I was wondering if there are particular algorithms/methods/databases (or software) available with these features. If not what would be the general approach in realizing these goals.

Comment: This is (1) an off-topic request for recommendations, (2) far too broad, and (3) a bit of a performance and storage nightmare in the making.

Comment: The question in current for is way too broad... It may be good idea to start with features of DB of your choice and see what is missing, or at least to know what you want to build - like [MS SQL Server Audit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx). Consider to narrow down your DB choice  and figure out your security/legal requirements to make the post more in scope for SO.